# How to write output of os.walk() to a file in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

Below Python code will read the "/home/sam" and traverse it using os.walk().

The three attributes that we get from os.walk(), that will be read using the "for" loop and then will be written to the file "Dir_traverse_date.txt"

My problem is when the program is done executing the code. The only word written to the file "Dir_traverse_date.txt" is -- `None`.

How to fix this ? How to get the output of the function into the text file

================================CODE=====================================

```
import os

def dir_trav():

    os.chdir("/home/sam")
    print("Current Directory", os.getcwd())
    for dirpath,dirname,filename in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        print ("Directory Path ----> ", dirpath)
        print ("Directory Name ----> ", dirname)
        print ("File Name      ----> ", filename)
    return




funct_out=dir_trav()

new_file=open('Dir_traverse_date.txt','w')

new_file.write(str(funct_out))

new_file.close()
```

========================================================================

Comment: `dir_trav` doesn't really return anything (which means it returns `None` and that's what you're writing to file).

Comment: You have to return something from the function.  Also worth noting, `os.walk` iterates over the given directory and its subdirectories.  Each iteration returns a directory path, the *list of subdirectories in that path*, and the *list of files in that path*.  It does not return one directory name and one file per iteration as your naming implies.

Comment: Provide an example of the file output you expect.

Comment: When is this going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In Python `return` must be followed by the object you wish the function to return. You can begin by manually placing a hard coded string in the return line. For example `return "To Sender"` Your file should now contain the text "To Sender" instead of "None". Try this with a few other strings or even numbers. Regardless of where you run `os.walk` your output will always be the same. What matters is what you place beside `return`.

Your goal is to construct a string from the the data gathered for you by `os.walk` and return it. I see that you are already printing some of the data. Let's begin fixing this by just gathering file names. Start off with an empty string and then accumulate your output with the `+=` operator.

```
def dir_trav():

    os.chdir("/home/sam")
    print("Current Directory", os.getcwd())

    output = ''
    for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        output += filename         

    return output
```

Now, you'll notice that your output will change to include filenames, but they'll all be stuck together end to end (e.g. file1file2file3) This is because we need to ensure that we insert newlines at after each piece of data we are extracting.

```
def dir_trav():

    os.chdir("/home/sam")
    print("Current Directory", os.getcwd())

    output = ''
    for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        output += filename + '\n'

    return output
```

From this point you should be able to move closer to the results you were looking for. String concatenation (+) is not the most efficient method for building strings from multiple data, but it will serve your purposes.

Note: Functions in Python can return multiple values, but they are technically a bound in a single object that is essentially a tuple.